# Unable to use an Image Loaded by the User in Flutter Dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart, image-processing

I've been checking all over stackOverflow and I couldn't find the answer.

I'm developing an app which request the user to upload an image and then I have a custom function which process the image information.

I successfully load the image with this command

```
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
```

My custom function required the image "Path" to process the image. I got the path with the following code:

```
File userImage = File(pickedFile.path);
String userImageLocation = userImage.toString();
```

But when I run the app I get the following error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: File: '/data/user/0/com.example.theappName/cache/image_picker5949959777536272090.jpg'
```

Then I noticed when I print the userImageLocation variable

```
File: '/data/user/0/com.example.theappName/cache/image_picker5949959777536272090.jpg'
```

It print the word "File", so I also tried removed the "File" word using substring but the outcome is still the same.

What am I missing?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Compare two images using  structural similarity index measure, I take an image from the user and I compare with the images I have pre-loaded in my assets

Comment: `String userImageLocation = userImage.path;` ??

Comment: Still the same error Will.